# while hosting ASP.NET 4.0 application under 3.5, config files shows conflicts

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a web site running in asp.net 3.5 and recently i had to build another web which i did in asp.net 4. while hosting the site(.net 4.0) under the one in 3.5, i am getting some config file issues, in the `<configsection>`, i have understood from research that this is due to the machine.config being inherited in the site with .net 4.0, how to override machine config here,`<clear/>` is not working.

Comment: Are you using `asp.net 4.0` frame work?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ for the main site its .net 3.5

Comment: As far I know you will net `asp.net 4.0` framework to host the application developed in `asp.net 4.0`. You need to create a new application pool with framework 4.0 and use that pool in your application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read every words of this Microsoft article to see what is side-by-side,

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a99txfy5(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a99txfy5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And then see what is the configuration you need to change,

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770150

It is rather complicated, so you have to pay enough attention to every details.